# tail latest data only, not the previous one

Tags: tail

I notice that when I use `tail -F`, I'm still getting a log generated a few minutes ago.

**Current date and time**

```
user@svr01:~$ date
Wed Jun 19 00:39:52 +08 2019
```

**`tail -F` shows data a few minutes before `date`**

```
user@svr01:~$ tail -F /var/log/syslog
Jun 19 00:34:26 svr01 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server6.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 19 00:34:26 svr01 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server6.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 00:34:56 svr01 systemd-networkd-wait-online[1485]: Event loop failed: Connection timed out
...
```

Would it be possible to **only** view log after current date and time which is after `Wed Jun 19 00:39:52 +08 2019` in this case, and not before that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can tell `tail` to start with no lines from the file, and it will only show lines added after it starts running:

```
tail -F -n 0 /var/log/syslog
```

By default `tail` shows the last ten lines of the file(s) it’s asked to process.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!!